# Edit the background of a button in c#

Tags: c#, image, winforms, button, colors

I have a little problem of mine to solve. I have a button which has an image background.I tried to color the whole button but the image can not be seen after coloring the whole button. How can I edit this "imagebutton" like in this example? https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaQQQ.png

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace bura
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (button2.BackgroundImage != null)
            {
                button2.BackgroundImage = null;
                button2.BackColor = Color.Black; 
            }

            else {
                button2.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch; 
                button2.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\rati\\Desktop\\ks.png");
            }

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button2.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            button2.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\rati\\Desktop\\ks.png");
        }
    }
}
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaQQQ.png)

Comment: Can you show some code? If i set the buttons `Image` and `Background` `Property`, I see both of them.

Comment: I just edited this post.now you can see the code :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm exactly understanding your problem, but if I start your example and I click on `button2`, then just the `BackgroundImage` and the `BackgroundImageLayout` gets set. If i click a second time on button2, then the `BackgroundImage` gets set to null and you just set the `BackColor`. If I click a third time on button2, I see the `BackgroundImage` and the `Color`.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XaQQQ.png you have the picture which represents a king(playing cards) and I need to do those black lines or a similar thing on the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your pictures with a method like this:

```
private static void DrawLinesOnBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
{
   using (var p = new Pen(Color.Black, 5))
   {
      using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
      {
         g.DrawLine(p, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
      }
   }
}
```

This method adds a line from the left top corner to the right bottom corner. Just draw some more lines and you should get your wanted result.

Comment: and how to make an image dim/wan?

Comment: What do you mean with "dim/wan"?

Comment: example, when you make a shortcut of something,the icon is getting another color like disappearing

Answer (score 2):

Just made a button by using the designer with the following code:

```
this.button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DodgerBlue;
this.button1.BackgroundImage = global::WindowsFormsApplication.Properties.Resources.ChargeImage;
this.button1.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Zoom;
this.button1.Image = global::WindowsFormsApplication.Properties.Resources.DatabaseImage;
this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
this.button1.Name = "button1";
this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(264, 160);
this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
```

And that is the result:

[image: Screenshot of button with image]

So what is your problem?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XaQQQ.png
you have the picture which represents a king(playing cards) and I need to do those black lines or a similar thing on the picture

Comment: Maybe subscribe to OnPaint of the button and use `e.Graphics.DrawLine()`?

Comment: I tried it but it does not work.if you manage to do it plz share code if you can